# get back all the checked values in a datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using [jquery datatable](https://datatables.net) and in order to check all the elements (pagination is used ) , the below code is used  :

```
$("[id$='checkAll']").on('click', function () {
  var rows = table.rows().nodes();
  $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

and all elements is getting checked

but the problem is in the code behind when I try to get back all of this elements with this code

```
protected void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  List<string> list = new List<string>();

  foreach (ListViewItem item in demandesExportPhytos.Items)
    {
    i++;
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("demandeCheckbox");
    if (checkbox.Checked == true)
        {
        j++;
        list.Add(item.ID);
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("///");
  }
```

j= 15 and i = to the number of elements shown on the interface ( pagination is used ) so it is 10 or 5 depending of the selected page 1 or 2 given all the elements are checked

Comment: I think the problem is due to that datable keep just the elements of the current page selected and remove others , so how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm, Well -1 for webforms. Anyway perhaps a different way of doing this. Say have a hidden element with json on the checked elements or comma delimited with the checked elements. Then onclick on the checkboxes to control that. Use that hidden to do whatever it is the testBtn_Click.

Just an idea

Comment: web forms is not my choice

Comment: Yeah, just been trying to learn it myself for a project that I'm being handed, not looking forward to it.